# Getting ID of dynamically added Views

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout, horizontalscrollview

How to get the id of dynamically added views?

I want to add buttons to `HorizontalScrollview` in button click but limit it to three or four rows, then it will create new `TableLayout` for another three - four rows repeatedly like below -

[image: THE IMAGE IS HERE]

How can I achieve this?

Below is my code:

```
public void addNewButton(int ids, TableLayout table){
    Button btn = new Button(challengemode.this);
    btn.setId(ids);
    btn.setText(String.valueOf("btn" + ids));
    btn.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    table.addView(btn);
    horizontalScrollView.removeAllViews();
    horizontalScrollView.addView(table);
}
```

Here is the XML,

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollViewGCode"
                android:layout_width="125pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <!--TABLE LAYOUT 1-->
                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tblLayout1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </TableLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: why do u need id?
cant u add Click listener while adding button?

Comment: @Chito Monte please explain in a clear way what is your problem, like "I would like to do xxx but instead I obtain yyy"

Comment: You can add click listener. And if you want to determine which index button, you can add tag to the button when it's created.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique ID for you view with [generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) method for API 17 or higher or you can use [ViewIdGenerator](https://gist.github.com/code4lifevn/7855c00ce7569824d2f8)  for lowest Android version.
Just modify you code to

```
    public void addNewButton(int ids, TableLayout table){
    Button btn = new Button(challengemode.this);
    btn.setId(ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId());
    btn.setText(String.valueOf("btn" + ids));
    btn.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    table.addView(btn);
    horizontalScrollView.removeAllViews();
    horizontalScrollView.addView(table);
}
```

Comment: How to retrieve the generated ID?

Comment: int id = ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId();btn.setId(id);

Answer (score 0):

Just use while adding

button.setTag(position);

while retrieving

button.getTag(position);